# Is ajax-api tag needed?

Tags: discussion

There is only one question under [ajax-api](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ajax-api) and largest part of AJAX Framework is accessible via Form API that has it's tag.

Comment: It's referred to as the [AJAX _Framework_](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21ajax.inc/group/ajax/7) so renaming might be more appropriate. There's no reason that couldn't stand on its own as a tag, but people obviously aren't using it

Comment: @Clive renaming to ajax-framework would make sense, but as far as I see simple [tag:ajax] is used for it now. I don't say it should get burninated, only that it has no value as it is now.

Answer (score 1):

Since there is [ajax](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ajax), I don't see any reason for having another tag that, in most of the cases, would be used together the existing one. Since AJAX should be done in Drupal using the existing AJAX framework, you would probably see [ajax](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ajax) and [ajax-api](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ajax-api) used in the same questions.

It is true that we have [forms](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/forms) and [form-api](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/form-api), but the first can be used about the form of an existing module, while the latter is used for the form API; in the first case, the question could not be about code. That is not true for [ajax](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ajax) and [ajax-api](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ajax-api), which are both about code, with the difference that (eventually) one would be used for generic AJAX code and the latter would be used for AJAX code using the Ajax framework. I don't see this distinction very useful, since the latter should always be the case in Drupal.

Comment: And most of AJAX Framework is in form api anyway, as the framework's site shows, so combination of [tag:form-api] and [tag:ajax] may do the trick nicely.

Comment: That's correct. I also fail to see the need of making a difference between AJAX code and AJAX code using the Ajax framework, since the latter should always be used with Drupal.

Comment: My question corrected as it's true I kinda underestimated AJAX Framework in it.